# No connection to Authorization server. Testdroid plugin for eclipse

Tags: android, robotium, gui-testing, testdroid

I installed testdroid plugin for eclipse and setup the proxy settings in Eclipse using:

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network connections
```

But when I am trying to authorize, I am getting the following error:

```
No connection to Authorization server.
```

I cannot understand, why testdroid plugin does not see Eclipse proxy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sees. Please try to clear the https schema if you have set it. Testdroid Cloud uses https so if you have set https schema for your proxy, (which probably is not ssl-proxy) it will try to use https schema and expects encrypted contents while your proxy gets plain text.

In most cases clearing https schema helps. I guess you suffer from this too.